# Extracting Numeric part with thousands separator and decimal point using regex in c# in a alpha numeric string

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to extract only the number part including the thousands separator and the decimal value , but always getting the error input string not in correct format .

My input string will be in the following formats

> USD1200 1,200.12 USD

I need the output as below respectively

> 1200 1,200.12

If I use the below the first occurrence of , is considered as delimiter

```
string prodValue = Regex.Match(prodAmount, @"\d+").Value;
```

If I use this one , I am getting error

```
string prodValue = Regex.Match(prodAmount, @"^[0-9]+(\,[0-9])+(\.[0-9])?$").Value;
```

How can I can extract the output I needed?

Comment: So you just need to RegEx replace anything that isn't 0-9, "," or "." ?

Comment: Try `Regex.Replace(s, @"[^0-9.,]+", "").Trim()`

Answer (score 2):

For capturing multiple matches, you need `Regex.Matches` instead of `Regex.Match` . Also in your regex, you need to make comma group as zero or more occurence and dot group as optional as it may or may not exist in the number you intend to capture.

You can use this regex,

```
\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?
```

**Explanation:**

- `\d+` --> Matches one or more digits
- `(?:,\d+)*` --> Matches a comma followed by one or more digits zero or more times
- `(?:\.\d+)?` --> Optionally matches a literal dot followed by one or more digits

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iMvnSB/1)

Here is a sample C# code,

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches("USD1200 1,200.12 1,211,234,332.12 12,333 USD", @"\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?");
for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count;i++) {
    Console.WriteLine("Match: " + matches[i]);
}
```

This gives following output like you expect,

```
Match: 1200
Match: 1,200.12
Match: 1,211,234,332.12
Match: 12,333
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you places the second "+" wrong and missed a third one.

```
@"^[0-9]+,[0-9]+\.[0-9]+?$")
```

Answer (score 0):

You `Regex` match string is incorrect.

Try: `^[0-9]+((,[0-9]+)+)?(\.[0-9]+)?$`

[See example here](https://regex101.com/r/c0FSp4/3)

Comment: You forgot to escape dot due to which it matches 10%2 or 10P2. Also you don't need to escape comma. With your usage of ^ and $ this regex will not be able to find multiple matches the way OP wants.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error. It seems I was in haste and removed the prefixing from the wrong character. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

In your regex you use anchors `^` to assert the start and the end `$` of the string where `USD` is not taken into consideration and would not match. If you want mulitple matches, you should use Regex.Matches instead.

To match a number without a dot or a comma, the middle part should match 0+ times as the last part is already optional and the digits in the character class need an quantifier to match 1+ times like `(,[0-9]+)*`. Note that you don't have to escape the comma.

If the `USD` is part of the match, you could use an alternation to match either USD1200 or 1,200.12 USD instead of matching all the digits.

You could use named capturing group to reference the group by name.

`\bUSD(?<n1>\d+)|(?<n2>\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?) USD\b`

That would match

- `\bUSD` Match word boundary and USD
- `(?<n1>\d+)` Named capturing group `n1` which will match 1+ digits
- `|` or
- `(?<n2>` Start named capturing group `n2`

  - `\d{1,3}` Match 1-3 digits
  - `(?:,\d{3})*` Match a comma, 3 digits and repeat 0+ times
  - `(?:\.\d+)?` Match a dot and 1+ digits and make that optional
- `)` Close namedd capturing group
- `USD\b` Match space, USD and a word boundary

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbUSD%28%3f%3cn1%3e%5cd%2b%29%7c%28%3f%3cn2%3e%5cd%7b1%2c3%7d%28%3f%3a%2c%5cd%7b3%7d%29*%28%3f%3a%5c.%5cd%2b%29%3f%29+USD%5cb&i=USD1200+1%2c200.12+USD) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/sUMdmE)